# magento 2 how to upload images and videos in custom module

Tags: magento2, image-upload

I am using magento 2.1

I need to upload multiple images and video using ui component

Like **magento-admin -> products -> caralog -> product**

[image]

what do i need to do to  achieve this ?

Comment: Still M2 use old style code for 'Image and Video' without UI_Component? Do you need this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally i got the answer

I refer this module and implement in my custom module

**Find below useful code :**

following below steps

1) create layout.xml

`[vendor]/[module]/operation/view/adminhtml/layout/layout_edit.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <uiComponent name="sample_form"/>
            </referenceContainer>
            <referenceContainer name="sample_form">
                <block name="gallery" class="[vendor]\[module]\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Helper\Form\Gallery">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Images</item>
                            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">22</item>
                            <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="[vendor]\[module]\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content" as="content" template="[vendor]_[[module]::helper/gallery.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="parentComponent" xsi:type="string">sample_form.sample_form.block_gallery.block_gallery</item>

                            </argument>
                        </arguments>

                    </block>
                </block>
            </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

2) Create helper block

`[vendor]/[module]/Block/Adminhtml/Grid/Helper/Form/Gallery.php`

```
namespace [vendor]\[module]\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Helper\Form;

use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;

class Gallery extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery
{
    /**
     * @var here you set your ui form 
     */
    protected $formName = 'sample_form';

}
```

3) Create helper form block

`[vendor]\[module]\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content.php`

```
namespace [vendor]\[module]\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Helper\Form\Gallery;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Media\Uploader;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Content extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content
{


    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->addChild('uploader', 'Magento\Backend\Block\Media\Uploader');

        $a = $this->getUploader()->getConfig()->setUrl(
            $this->_urlBuilder->addSessionParam()->getUrl('[vendor]/grid_gallery/upload')/* here set you upload Controller */
        )->setFileField(
            'image'
        )->setFilters(
            [
                'images' => [
                    'label' => __('Images (.gif, .jpg, .png)'),
                    'files' => ['*.gif', '*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.png'],
                ],
            ]
        );

    }


    public function getImageTypes()
    {
        return '[]';
    }

    public function getMediaAttributes()
    {
        return '[]';
    }

}
```

**Note**  :- you should extends properly above both blocks

4) Create template

You should copy gallery.phtml form `vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/adminhtml/templates/helper/gallery.phtml`
and modified it as par your requirement and pest in your module `[vendor]/[module]/view/adminhtml/templates/helper/gallery.phtml`

Please let me know in comment if you need any help

Comment: i am getting error as OBJECT DOM document should be created

Comment: @vijayb can you please put this error here

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XtS-7XQ6Rj2ZhM-Sp6j4_WkQhXRpyV4ziAlG3_DICN0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @vijayb I hop you working on ui form so set here your ui form name `protected $formName = 'your_ui_form`

Comment: i followed the every step exactly as explained in answer.do we have to create any other file to define that Ui Component??

Comment: @vijayb no this is not define any other file. ;
can you please compare your layout with `/vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_product_form.xml`

Comment: @Deexit Sanghani you are a rock star! Thxs. You forgot to add the template path inside `[vendor]\[module]\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content.php` Something like this worked for me: `protected $_template = '[vendor]_[module]::helper/gallery.phtml';`

Comment: @DanielKratohvil Thanks..:)  Glad to help !! Keep helping.. :)

Comment: I integrated this solution, but getting only a blank page with an "Add Video" button. When I click on that button, nothing will happen.

Comment: @DeexitSanghani  is it working for add videos or we can just implement multiple image uploader?

Comment: @VIPINAROY did you find the working solution ?

Comment: @Deexit Sanghani  I've followed the steps above but nothing happened! Are you sure it's in the layout and not in ui_component folder as <htmlContent>?

Comment: @DeexitSanghani here Display error in  **Call to a member function getImages() on null**
in product Edit page backend side in magento 2.3.3 version

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Deexit Sanghani  may be out dated as i am using magento2.2.2 v and the the location for the xml din't work for me `[vendor]/[module]/operation/view/adminhtml/layout/layout_edit.xml` but everything else is about right so up-voted as well. And heres is what worked for me
take a look in `../vendor/magento/module-product-video/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml` and in you module location:`../app/code/[vendor]/[module]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/your_ layout_edit.xml` within the `<form></form>` add:

```
    <htmlContent name="gallery" sortOrder="22">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="wrapper" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Custom Images And Videos</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <wrapper>
                <canShow>true</canShow>
                <componentType>fieldset</componentType>
            </wrapper>
        </settings>
        <block name="gallery" class="[vendor]\[module]\Block\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Helper\Form\Gallery">
            <!--<arguments>
                <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Images And Videos</item>
                    <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">22</item>
                    <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>-->
            <block class="[vendor]\[module]\Block\Adminhtml\[Entity]\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content" as="content">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="parentComponent" xsi:type="string">ui_component_form.ui_component_form.block_gallery.block_gallery</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\ProductVideo\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\NewVideo" name="new-video" template="Magento_ProductVideo::product/edit/slideout/form.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
    </htmlContent>
```

I have manage to upload image add custom roles etc.. but not save in database yet against a row, **NOTE:** It needs a lot of attention to make it works for your needs, overwrite to your needs e.g `gallery.pthml`, `getImagesJson()`, `getImageTypes()`, `getMediaAttributes` methods etc... and then it needs closely matches database structure that follows the same patterns or similar to native magento look table:  `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`,`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`,`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` etc... Haven't worked on the video yet!

Hope that help someone!

Comment: Did you work on video ?

Comment: @Deepak. No. I have not needed it!

Comment: Ok, actually I stuck here.

Comment: @JulianoVargas   Followed the exact steps and nothing  rendering return as not defined in product-gallery.js file. ( Using category_form.xml)

Answer (score -1):

To add video in Magento 2, you have to follow these steps:

1. Generate a Youtube API Key.
2. Integration of the Youtube API key to
3. Magento 2. Integration of the Youtube Video URL to Product.