# How I can add Gallery Images for custom form in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, adminform, gallery-image

I am creating a Custom form in admin of magento 2,and I want to add media gallery for same product form(Images and video Tab https://prnt.sc/w926fk ) into this form https://prnt.sc/w928bi

please help me with this issue . Thank much!

Answer (score 0):

First you check magenot 2 default xml file like :- **`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml`** and check magento default code

[image]

And same as edit code in your custom module.And Below links is helpful

Please can your try this link :-

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/158504/85907

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/186781/85907

If any query Please ask me.

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: I was able to add the "Images And Videos" on my custom form, but why current images was not added on the gallery even if my product has current images and also I used product collection. Also tried adding "->addMediaGalleryData()" on the collection but still no images.